# Booting into ubuntu hangs before logon screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus laptop. I had been using it for a couple of hours, then wanted to reboot for a minor keyboard setting. I had already rebooted many times for other settings: and this setting was just a tweak to keyboard rate and would not affect boot-ability.

But now when starting `ubuntu` the violet ubuntu background color screen - without any graphics -  appears once then flickers to black then comes on again. Then after maybe 30 seconds the following is displayed.. and no further progress occurs:

[image]

If I try to shut down by hitting the power button briefly the following screen shows:

[image]

What can I do to diagnose the problem?
But nothing further happens.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link how to edit grub to put in `nomodeset`. This solved the problem for me. I've found out that it happens alot on computer with Nvidia graphics card because Nvidia requires a special graphics driver that isn't there on default ubuntu installations and the driver that gets auto chosen is not fully supported so boots will hang and screens will look weird.

it boots strange sometimes after putting in the nomodeset but it always comes out good once finally booted. i tried the permanent nomodeset option that it describes but it seemed to mess up using that for me so i have to do the bootup option each time i restart.

[nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: I ended up nuking the installation so am unable to test this at the moment. But I'll keep this in mind !

Comment: `nomodeset` is not a solution, just a workaround. While booting with it **install the Nvidia proprietary drivers**, that's the solution. There are literally thousands of good answers mentioning it,  no need for this one.

Comment: I had the same problem and looked for hours, all those proprietary drivers crashed mine even further so I'd say it's very relevent.